# Generate Minified Sencha Architect project with Sencha cmd or SDK

Tags: javascript, extjs, minify, sencha-architect

I have my project in *Sencha Architect 2.2.2 Build: 991.*

I'm trying to create one file that contains only the extjs classes and my project code, because the idea is to load only one js file, not *app-all.js* and *ext-all.js* files in the page.

**index.html:**

```
<!-- Auto Generated with Sencha Architect -->
<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>My Site</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/ext/resources/ext-theme-classic/ext-theme-classic-all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/list.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="res/ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res/ext/locale/ext-lang-pt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

**And I use:**

```
sencha create jsb sudo -a http://.../index.html -p app.jsb3  --verbose
sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d . -v
```

And it creates two files classes app-all.js and all-classes.js.
app-all.js in theory have all the code minified (including extjs classes because I'm using ext-dev.js into the include.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="res/ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
```

But if I include only *app-all.js* class in my html it says that it dont know what is Ext, that's undefined. If I add *ext-all.js* it works, but thats not the idea...

Thanks

Comment: I get "unknown command: create" when I try that command. Sencha 2.2.1 Cmd 3.1.2.342

Comment: I also get unknown command: create Sencha Cmd 4.0.0